# Realm Database read data from Android

Tags: android, realm

I am new to `realm` database so need some help. When I kill my app then come back to the app again, I am unable to retrieve the data which was saved in `retrofit`. Insertion is working perfectly. Here is my code :

Insert Code inside callJson Method:

```
 realm.beginTransaction();
 realmCities = realm.copyToRealm(clientContactList);
 realm.commitTransaction();
```

Response after inserting when i am logging :

```
path :  /data/data/com.xyz.da/files/default.realm
response from realm : E/Output: ClientContact = proxy[{clientName:A},{email:mit@email.com},{address:Palava},{contactPerson:Amit},{numberMobile:9930182464},{numberLandline:25123456},{groupName:B},{tumbnailColor:0}]ClientContact = proxy[{clientName:A1},{email:abc@email.com},{address:MBP},{contactPerson:John},{numberMobile:9876543210},{numberLandline:25123456},{groupName:B1},{tumbnailColor:0}]ClientContact = proxy[{clientName:A10},{email:abc@email.com},{address:MBP},{contactPerson:John},{numberMobile:9876543210},{numberLandline:25123456},{groupName:E2},{tumbnailColor:0}]
```

In onCreateView I am doing like this : Here when i kill app and come back `realmCities` List coming null so it again hitting `callJson()`

```
if(realmCities!=null && realmCities.size()>0){
    Log.e("realmCities",""+realmCities.size());
}else{
    callJSON();
}
```

Comment: Is this `realm.beginTransaction();
 realmCities = realm.copyToRealm(clientContactList);
 realm.commitTransaction();` in your service ? or doing in background task ?

Comment: background task

Comment: See if your background task is executing well

Comment: Yeah , i am able to insert the data , as you can see above , when i am logging the data it's inserting

Comment: you have inserted data but when app is restart you have to get data from database

Comment: yes but it's not happening right now in on create i had wrote above code

Comment: You would have had to query the data from the database with `realm.where()...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have inserted data but when app is restart you have to get data from database

```
 realm.beginTransaction();
 realmCities = realm.copyToRealm(clientContactList);
 realm.commitTransaction();
```

when restart the app you have to get data from database like :

```
RealmResults<ClientContact> realmCities= realm.where(ClientContact.class).findAllAsync();    
                        //fetching the data
        realmCities.load();
```

and after that you have to check condition

```
if(realmCities!=null && realmCities.size()>0){
    Log.e("realmCities",""+realmCities.size());
}else{
    callJSON();
}
```

Comment: i add realmCities.load(); but not fix my problem