# How to retrieve data from the realm database file available in android

Tags: android, database, realm

I have a realm database file available in the android asset folder. So how to manipulate data from the available realm database file.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407852/realm-database-read-data-from-android

Answer (score 0):

You should copy your realm file from assets to file directory, because you can only read files from assets, not write them : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845559/1243048

To open an asset file : [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Copy file from assets : [android:- how to copy image from Assets to SD Card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943448/android-how-to-copy-image-from-assets-to-sd-card)

To set realm file path when creating configuration : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#configuring-a-realm

Answer (score -1):

Try this in background thread:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
MyData data = new MyData(); // extends RealmObject
realm.insertOrUpdate(data);
realm.close();
```

Enclose it in try-catch-finally.

Comment: that does not answer the question at all